# Redirect lost control of search results

Tags: redirects

Our domain is: suncitypickleballclub.org

We have moved our website to a cloud service on CourtReserve.com

Our domain has a hard (301) redirect to: https://app.courtreserve.com/Online/Portal/Index/9090

Entering URL suncitypickleballclub.org goes to https://app.courtreserve.com/Online/Portal/Index/9090

All good, however search results for "Sun City Pickleball" & "Sun City Pickleball Club" are displaying links to:

https://suncityaz.org/recreation/clubs/pickleball-club/ and to Facebook

We need the search results to display a link to:

https://app.courtreserve.com/Online/Portal/Index/9090

The old website has no presence and the cloud service provides no account based SEO. How do we claim our new website in the search results?

Comment: Time and patience.  Search results aren't updated overnight, it can take some time.

Comment: Are you no longer going to use suncitypickleballclub.org?

Comment: We have moved replaced the WordPress website with a cloud service; however we retain the domain. This took places months ago so the search problem is not going away by itself.

Comment: Many cloud services allow you to assign a domain name to your content just like you could with Wordpress.  Is that not an option in this case?

Comment: Yes, CourtReserve was my first go to on that; however they don't provide any SEO support.